# gradual color change by a variable

Tags: css, sass

I want to have some visual notification when something is good, bad or in between

lets say I have a number between 0 and 100, where 100 is green (or some other predefined color) and 0 is red (or another color)

is there a way to get the color that is 67? 34? 98? with only css

so 67 in this case, could either be `(67 * green + 33 * red) / 100` or some other function

another alternative would be to make a gradient (but then it wouldn't be a solid color..)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no stable way to do that in CSS, only. CSS calc() property will probably the way to go as the W3C specs include that you can use values from attr() for calculations. As of now, no browser supports the combination of both, but it would look like this

```
// HTML
<span class="color" data-val="67">67</span>

// CSS
.color {
  background-color: rgb(
    calc( (100 - attr(data-val)) / 100 * 255 ),
    calc( attr(data-val) / 100 * 255),
    0
  );
}
```

calc() itself works quite well (with prefixes in Chrome (-webkit-) and Firefox (-moz-), but the numbers used for calculation must be set in CSS (e.g. `width: calc(100% - 3em);`).

Before attr() is fully supported inside calc(), you probably need to use javascript to achieve that, see example below where the span has a red background and the inner strong element has a green background color. Javascript is used to set the background opacity based on the text value. Press **Run code snippet** to see the result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.color').each(function() {
        $(this).children('strong').css('background-color', 'rgba(0,255,0,'+(parseInt($(this).text()) / 100)+')');
    });
});
```

```css
.color {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #c00;
}
strong {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="color"><strong>100</strong></span>
<span class="color"><strong>67</strong></span>
<span class="color"><strong>33</strong></span>
<span class="color"><strong>25</strong></span>
<span class="color"><strong>0</strong></span>
```

Comment: How would your theoretical `calc()` solution work with more complicated colors for your endpoints like #668920 and #995413?  You seem to have focused a lot of time on a solution that doesn't work, and failed to provide the code for a solution that *will* work (links to off-site code aren't good enough).

Comment: The question aimed for a solution to indicate a number's value in a range between red and green using CSS/SASS. My answer provides the information that there is no way currently with CSS, only, but shows what we might be using in the near future (as calc() and attr() are both pat of W3C's recommendation). Up to that near future, one will probably have to use javascript as the most efficient solution. I provided such a solution but since the questions intent was to ask for pure CSS solutions, I didn't elaborate on the JS version.

Comment: As for more complex numbers/color codes: this can easily be achieved by writing more complex calc() statements. If you want to, you could even calculate the opacity by using rgba() color codes.

Comment: You're not getting it.  Your answer amounts to "here is a bunch of code that doesn't work and a link to some code that works but may or may not still be here by the time you read this answer".  see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: I was getting what you were aiming at. My point was, that the JS version is NOT an answer to the question of how to do it with CSS, only. So, imho the JS part was kind of a bonus but irrelevant to the OP's question. For the sake of it, I added the code snippets here.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this with CSS is to write a class for every single possible color.  The only way Sass can help is by programatically generating all of your classes:

```
@for $i from 0 through 100 {
  .foo-#{$i} {
    background: mix(red, green, $i * 1%);
  }
}
```

This task can be more efficiently solved via JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

You can but it requires SASS or LESS or another pre-processor that allows CSS variables

```
SASS

$value: 0;
$green: 255*($value/100);
$red:255*((100-$value)/100);


div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
  background:rgb($red, $green , 0);
}
```

[**SassMeister Demo**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/427656418535a5842e35)

Comment: The problem is, that the `$value` is in the HTML and thus not known to the SASS script.

Comment: Not sure where it says that in the question.

Comment: You are right, it's not explicitly stated, but I assumed to be that way as OP is talking about visual notification. I guess there's some value output to some monitoring website and he wants to add the color based on that (prior unknown to him) value.

Comment: Our solutions are effectively the same. Both are hardcoded somewhere. I'm sure we both realise that the real solution would be a javascript one.

Comment: Sorry to disagree on the first part. Even though it's not available yet, as soon as calc() is supported in combination with attr(), we will be able to set almost any values in CSS based on the HTML output (from element attributes). Of course, the monitoring site would need to put the value in an attribute.

Comment: But again, IFF (programming pun intended) that will be possible, your solution will be way easier to read as we could do the math operation before and store the result in variables.